# Magento 2.3 - Get category of item related foreach

Tags: magento2.3, category, related-products

I want to load the category name and category url of the item that is displayed as a related item on the productpage.

So inside the foreach element, I want to load the category name and url of the related item itself.

How can I get the category name of a item in Magento 2.3?

I tried the following that seems to work well, but I do not want to a load a objectManager on frontend, so what is the best way to load this otherwise?

```
<?php $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');
$categories = $product->getCategoryIds(); /*will return category ids array*/
foreach($categories as $category){
    $cat = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($category);
    echo $cat->getName();
    }

?>
```

HTML:

```
                                    <?php $items = $block->getProductCollection()->getItems();?>
                <?php foreach ($items as $item) : ?>
                    <?= /* @noEscape */ ($iterator++ == 1) ? '' : '</' . $tag . '>' ?><<?= /* @noEscape */ $tag?> class="product-item">
                    <div class="product">
                        <div class="product-details col-sm-7">
                                <a title="<?= $block->escapeHtml($item->getName()) ?>"
                                   href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getProductUrl($item)) ?>"
                                   class="product-item-link">
                                    <?= $block->escapeHtml($item->getName()) ?>
                                </a>
                            <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getProductPriceHtml($item, \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice::PRICE_CODE) ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="product-action col-sm-12">
                            <?php $CatName = $block->getCategoryCollection();
                                echo '<PRE>';print_r($CatName);?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php endforeach ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a module and override `catalog_product_view.xml` in your module. then create one block to set your business logic to the template.

> Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
            <container name="productdetailcat"  htmlTag="div" htmlClass="productdetailcat"  after="product.info.price">
                <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Custom" name="catnameurl" template="Vendor_Module::custom_cat.phtml" />
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> Vendor/Module/Block/Custom.php

```
   <?php 

namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Category;

class Custom extends Template
{
    private $_registry;
    private $_categoryFactory;
    private $_productFactory;
    protected $_category;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Config $pageConfig,
        Registry $registry,
        Category $catgory,
        CategoryFactory $categoryfactory,
        ProductFactory $productFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->pageConfig = $pageConfig;
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryfactory;
        $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->_category = $catgory;
    }

    public function getCategoryCollection($productId) 
    {
        $product = $this->_productFactory->create()->load($productId);
        $categories = $product->getCategoryIds();
        foreach($categories as $category)
        {
            $cat = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($category);
            $caturl = $cat->getUrl();
            $catName = $cat->getName();
        }

        return $catName;
    }
}

?>
```

> Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/custom_cat.phtml

```
<?php $items = $block->getProductCollection()->getItems();?>
<?php foreach ($items as $item) : ?>
    <?= /* @noEscape */ ($iterator++ == 1) ? '' : '</' . $tag . '>' ?><<?= /* @noEscape */ $tag?> class="product-item">
    <div class="product">
        <div class="product-details col-sm-7">
            <a title="<?= $block->escapeHtml($item->getName()) ?>"
               href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getProductUrl($item)) ?>"
               class="product-item-link">
                <?= $block->escapeHtml($item->getName()) ?>
            </a>
        <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getProductPriceHtml($item, \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice::PRICE_CODE) ?>
        </div>
        <div class="product-action col-sm-12">
        <?php $CatName = $block->getCategoryCollection($item->getId());
            echo '<PRE>';print_r($CatName);?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

or

use the below code in your template under related foreach. add your block path `Vendor\Module\Block\Custom` instead of your block name.

```
$blockObj= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\Custom');
$custmcatBlock = $blockObj->getCategoryCollection($item->getId());
echo '<PRE>';print_r($custmcatBlockatName);
```

Here is display last category name because in foreach return the last name. as per your logic custom in our code and display all cat names and URLs. If You have any query please let me know.

I hope this will help you....!

Comment: Thanks! I tried this, but I get a error; `Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type Error occurred when creating object: Vendor\GetCategoryName\Block\CurrentCategory
<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Vendor\GetCateg...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70]`

Comment: try to remove generated folder and hit upgrade abd deploy command and then check

Comment: try to comment your object manager code also

Comment: Thanks, I tried both, but it still shows the same error.

Comment: can you upload a block file in your question?

Comment: I want to load it inside the foreach of the related products, so maybe its due to the item foreach? So it should not check the main product, but the item that is a related product. See my updated question.

Comment: let me check @JGeer

Comment: above your template file  is a custom template or Magento core template

Comment: Its custom, but it is based on the default related products element.

Comment: hey @JGeer I have update my block file and template code also please check

Comment: pass related product id to the getCategoryCollection($item->getId()) function

Comment: Thanks, but I still get the same error. Maybe it's due to the `class Custom extends Template`. I can not load it easily into the xml template, so I need to load it using `<?php $category = $this->helper('Vendor\GetCategoryName\Block\CurrentCategory');?>`

Comment: check again I have updated my code.

Comment: Thanks again! But I get `Vendor\GetCategoryName\Block\CurrentCategory doesn't extends Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper`

Comment: in your block file, you extend AbstractHelper. please extend Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template. replace in Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Works fine now! :)

Comment: cool...! Finally, solve it